# custom Frame menu bar - electron

Tags: electron

my question is how can I make a custom menu bar for new window that loads URL not file in my local.

```
newWin = new BrowserWindow({ parent: win, width: 1200, height: 800, frame: false, show: true})
newWin.loadURL('https://foo.bar')
```

so I know I can use { frame: false } and inject some HTML CSS tags for handling this. https://github.com/binaryfunt/electron-seamless-titlebar-tutorial . according to this useful article. but what about loading URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BrowserView](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view) inside a BrowserWindow where you put your custom title bar.

You can image BrowserView like an iframe.